# Is this true for Jacobsthal Numbers? (I still need an Answer)

Tags: sequences-and-series

The Sequence: 1, 1, 3, 5, 11, 21, 43, 85 (Find the Next Term Which is: 171)

--Edit: Appears to be the previous term plus twice the term before.

--Edit Ex: 11 = 5 + 2(3)

And this is true while finding the next term after 45.

---

However, can you check if my solution is also valid for this Jacobsthal Sequence?

2 × (Previous term) - 1 (if it's an even counted term -- like 1, 5, 21, and 85)

Or

2 × (Previous term) + 1 (if it's an odd counted term -- like 1, 3, 11, and 43)

Please check if this works.

Comment: Each term is the sum of the three previous terms? $1+3+5\neq11$  I don't see any term that is the sum of the three previous terms.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I made a huge mistake, and copied the wrong solution from my textbook.